# Want flexbox button to take up newline when the text inside is too long

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 2 flexbox buttons in my page and when I internationalize and change to german, the buttons are long and the text forms two lines inside the button. But I want the button to take up the entire width when text is long and the second button to fill up the second row. How do I do that?

https://codepen.io/sahanaravi/pen/NWKdxee

```
  <h3>2 buttons in a line</h3>
<div class="button-area-line">
  <a href="#">Button one with a lot more text than others mbjbjb jhgjhgjhg lkjlkjkj</a>
  <a href="#">Button two info jhgjhgjgh </a>
</div>

<h3>2 buttons in a line</h3>
<h3>Want this to wrap and become single button in a line instead of text taking but 2 lines inside the button</h3>
<div class="button-area-line">
  <a href="#">Button one with a lot more text than others mbjbjb jhgjhgjhg lkjlkjkj Button one with a lot more text than others mbjbjb jhgjhgjhg lkjlkjkj</a>
  <a href="#">Button two info jhgjhgjgh kjhkjhkjhjhhkjkjhkjhkjhkj hgjhgjhgjhgjhg </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to set wrap this way: `flex-wrap: wrap` for this. See the pen:  https://codepen.io/saqibameen/pen/rNBjeNe

Answer (score 1):

Allow wrapping on the parent flex container and set the links to `nowrap`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.button-area-line {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.button-area-line a {
  background: #999;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: .3em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-area-line">
  <a href="#">Button one with a lot more text than others mbjbjb jhgjhgjhg lkjlkjkj Button one with a lot more</a>
  <a href="#">Button two info jhgjhgjgh kjhkjhkjhjhhkjkjhkjhkjhkj hgjhgjhgjhgjhg </a>
</div>
```